# EXC_BAD_ACCESS during insert in a std::set

Tags: c++, macos, stl

I'm encountering an EXC_BAD_ACCESS problem with a C++ program on Mac OS X Lion, gcc 4.6.4, within the STL library. I manage a set of pointers: std::set, "symbols" being a class, and for a reason that I don't understand, the program eventually crashes when trying to insert in the set (I can do many insert and erase before).
GDB gives the following:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x0000000100003a79 in std::less<symbols*>::operator() (this=0x1002013e8, __x=@0x7fff5fbff240, __y=@0x3000100201400) at stl_function.h:236
236       { return __x < __y; }
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0000000100003a79 in std::less<symbols*>::operator() (this=0x1002013e8, __x=@0x7fff5fbff240, __y=@0x3000100201400) at stl_function.h:236
#1  0x0000000100003162 in std::_Rb_tree<symbols*, symbols*, std::_Identity<symbols*>, std::less<symbols*>, std::allocator<symbols*> >::_M_insert_unique (this=0x1002013e8, __v=@0x7fff5fbff240) at stl_tree.h:1277
#2  0x0000000100002cc3 in std::set<symbols*, std::less<symbols*>, std::allocator<symbols*> >::insert (this=0x1002013e8, __x=@0x7fff5fbff240) at stl_set.h:410
```

I don't understand why this std::less function would crash: it simply does a pointer comparison...

I have traced all calls to this std::less::operator() functions; as far as I understand when inserting/removing from a set there are a few calls to compare the input value to reference values (probably reference values in the nodes of the RB tree), and the crash always occurs when this 0x3000100201400 value is used in std::less. That's the only clue I have. Any idea?

Thanks

EDIT: I add that the code works properly on Ubuntu. Something else: I replaced the std::set by a std::list and replaced the insert/erase by push_back/remove and I also get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (of course the callstack is different but it still involves the insertion of the same pointer into the structure).

Comment: `At address: 0x0000000000000000` looks like a null pointer access.

Comment: Either that's not the entire callstack, or you have a serious buffer overwrite problem. (The value of `__x` is 17.59 terabytes, `__y` is 105.6 terabytes, and all the `this`-pointers are the same, which looks either overwritten or uninitialized.)

Comment: That's not the entire callstack, there are some function calls in my code that lead to the call to std::set<symbol*>::insert, I just put the callstack starting from the insert. What do you mean 17.59 terabytes? where do you get this information?